# Busy Wait Avoidance

Tags: network-programming

The operating system can avoid busy wait of a process by putting it to sleep and restoring it in case of an event. For restoring the operating system needs to check on the event occurance, it means the operating system or some part of it is struck in busy wait ? 
Is it possible to have a interrupt driven I/O in software context?
Only Between I/O and process not between  processes.

Answer (score 0):

> For restoring the operating system needs to check on the event occurance, it means the operating system or some part of it is struck in busy wait?

No.

> Is it possible to have a interrupt driven I/O in software context?

Yes.

> Only Between I/O and process not between processes.

Yes.

Computers haven't used busy-wait for I/O since about 1957.